# Why are my zero values returning as the maximum value in my running total in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, cumulative-sum

I am a novice user of PowerBi, so please bear with me. I have a table that is to return running totals in a descending order. As such, you would expect the values to continuously decrease as you move down the table. I noticed one column didn't follow that, so I check the raw data and those final two rows should have actually returned a zero. Below is the quick measure that I generated to get these values.

```
Count of Candidate running total in Last Recruiting Stage = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Sheet1'[Candidate]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Sheet1'[Last Recruiting Stage]),
        ISONORAFTER('Sheet1'[Last Recruiting Stage], MIN('Sheet1'[Last Recruiting Stage]), ASC)
    ))
```

Below is the table that is generated. The column to note is the Veterans at each stage. It should go (from top to bottom) 5, 5, 5, 3, 0, 0.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what your table looks like? The column used in the formula is "Last Recruiting Stage", whereas it is sliced by "Recruiting Stage" in the image. Are they different columns?

Comment: They are the same column, I just renamed it on my table.